# load ajax page with bootstrap modal in it, and auto launch that modal, all at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a button on my main page to call a modal from another page.

and I need this modal to be launched automatically after it is loaded.

I didn't find anything about it. (Or did I miss it?!)

my code:

I'm calling this js function:

```
<script>
function startb(plc)
{
    $.ajax({
             url: "gb.php?plc="+plc
          }).done(function( data ) {
           $("#large-div").html(data);
          });   

    //the id of the modal in the gb.php code is: "inside-modal"
      $('#inside-modal').modal('show');

}
</script>

<body>

<div id="large-div" name="large-div">

</div>

<button onclick="startb('28')">start plc</button>



</body>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried and I'd be happy to help you figure out what you're missing.

Comment: ajax the page you want to load then populate the modal when ajax is done. It's quite easy.

Comment: I inserted the code. thanx!!

Comment: the ajax request is asynchronous. Maybe adding the show modal line into the done section will make the code work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to place the $().modal() function call within the callback function of the ajax request**

AJAX, by definition is asynchronous, so the

```
.modal()
```

call happens before the div is actually populated with your new HTML content.

**Solution:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "gb.php?plc="+plc
      }).done(function( data ) {
        $("#large-div").html(data);
        $('#inside-modal').modal('show');
      });
```

Hope it helps

## Edit:

@ Dimitris Nastos, did not see your comment - exactly the same as this answer. Will upvote comment.

Comment: Thanx! it worked. 
before - I tried calling the modal from different places like outside the ajax call or from a different function. I didn't even think that calling it from within the ajax call is possible because the js code was not created even after the ajax call was done (i checked with an alert to see when it is finished adding the page) - s\this surprised me - but it is working - thanx!!! upvoted!